# What does "you can watch me whine it" mean?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

In the song "Crew" by Raye, one of the lyrics is "So when you see me at the party, you can watch me whine it". What does this mean and why?

Edit (As someone voted to close as they think it's opinion-based): I'd be happy with any single possible explanation of this phrase. I have no idea what it could mean. This line is part of the chorus and repeated multiple times in the lyrics. Happy for someone to comment or propose an edit if they think my question could be made more specific.

Comment: I think your question is fine and answerable. There is a prohibition on interpreting song lyrics but I don’t think it applies here as you are asking about a dialectal meaning of one word in context.

Comment: How is this primarily opinion-based?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod I have no idea, but 3 people (so far) have VTCd based on that rationale...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context. “Whine” is a style of dance. From [a blog on the Internet](https://laifrances.wordpress.com/2016/02/28/rihanna-got-me-so-inspired-to-write-this/):

> Whine is defined by a Caribbean dance expert as the thrusting or rotating of the pelvic girdle in a rhythmic pattern. … In the context of Caribbean culture, whine is a genuine regional dance form.

From this, “to whine it” is to do this dance.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I needed to know. And thanks for answering before my question would have been (inexplicably) closed for being "opinion based"!